# Change ToC depth mid document

Tags: table-of-contents

How do I change the ToC depth mid document?

so in this example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{hello}

 \frontmatter          

 \chapter{hello}

 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
 \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter

 \chapter{hello}
 \section{hello}
 \subsection{hello}
 \subsubsection{hello}

 \chapter{hello}

 \appendix

 \setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

 \chapter{hello}
 \section{hello}
 \subsection{hello}
 \subsubsection{hello}

\end{document}
```

[image: example]

But I want the ToC depth in the appendix to only be of depth 1 (while the rest of the document stays in tocdepth 3). I tried the `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` right after `\appendix` but that didn't do anything as you can see...

(my guess would be that the ToC is build right after I call `\tableofcontents` thus I can't change it afterwards this way)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write the change in tocdepth into the toc like shown in this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,oneside]{book}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{hello}

 \frontmatter

 \chapter{hello}

 \setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
 \tableofcontents

 \mainmatter

 \chapter{hello}
 \section{hello}
 \subsection{hello}
 \subsubsection{hello}

 \chapter{hello}

 \appendix

 \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}

 \chapter{hello}
 \section{hello}
 \subsection{hello}
 \subsubsection{hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution does work for this example but it doesn't work in my real project which uses \input{} to put in all the different chapters  (I use a different .tex file for every chapter). 

If I then add your line I get the error "undefined control sequence" and if I compile again that error changes to "missing } inserted. \tableofcontents". 

Any idea how to resolve this? (Else I'll just make a follow up question if this is not clear enough)

Comment: Yes, so do I (partition the text into multiple tex-files). Generally it should work, so I would propose you show another fine example (the one above is really well written). You may of course add it to this question!

Comment: I ran into the same problem as LinG, this helped: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395856/switching-tocdepth-in-the-middle-of-a-document