# How to fix: "deeper" PDF bookmarks disappear when \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}} is added

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, counters, bookmarks, appendix

My `book` class-based document normally has structure Chapter -> Section -> Subsection -> Subsubsection. And usually, PDF bookmarks in a PDF viewer (e.g. Adobe Reader) reflect just that. Here is one MWE with expected behaviour:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{bookmark}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents
    
    \chapter{Test C}
    A
    \section{Test C1}
    B
    \subsection{Test C11}
    C
    \subsubsection{Test C111}
    D
    
    \include{Testing bookmarks}
    
\end{document}
```

where `Testing bookmarks.tex` is

```
\appendix
%\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\chapter{Test A}
A
\section{Test A1}
B
```

The bookmarks are as expected:

[image: Expected bookmark structure. Picture 1]

---

***However***, when `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}` is ***added/uncommented*** under `Testing bookmarks.tex`, two of the deeper level bookmarks have *disappeared*.

[image: Broken/incomplete bookmark structure. Picture 2]

How can I fix this?

- Please make sure to compile the document a suitable number of times when making changes (here, sometimes three).
- (The MWE is indeed very minimal when compared to the original document.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}` seems to *somehow* change the default behaviour of bookmarks with `hyperref`.

But fixing it was (eventually) straightforward: just adding `bookmarksdepth=3` to the setup works like a charm. So

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[estonian]{babel}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false, bookmarksdepth=3]{hyperref} % changed line
%\usepackage{bookmark}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{Test C}
    A
    \section{Test C1}
    B
    \subsection{Test C11}
    C
    \subsubsection{Test C111}
    D

    \include{Testing bookmarks}

\end{document}
```

This gives the expected bookmark structure:

[image: Bookmark structure, with bookmarksdepth=3]