# Switching tocdepth in the middle of a document

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

The granularity of the table of contents is generally controlled by the counter `tocdepth` that can be set globally for the whole document.

Is it possible to change the granularity of the table of contents in the middle of a document, and if so, how?

I have a particular document where I want to have a `tocdepth` of two for the first part and a `tocdepth` of one in the second part (nothing more complicate).

Comment: The word `granularity` is a little bit confusing, in my point of view

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Write the `\setcounter{tocdepth}{...}` command to the `.toc` file directly with `\addtocontents`, as done in the `\changelocaltocdepth` macro:

This works since the various `\l@....` macros that basically generate the contents line entry check for the `tocdepth` value at the time of generating the `.toc` via `\@dottedtocline`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\newcommand{\changelocaltocdepth}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}}%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}%
}




\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\part{One}
\chapter{Foo}

\section{Foo}

\subsection{Foo stuff}

\changelocaltocdepth{1}

\part{Two}
\chapter{Foo}

\section{Foo}

\subsection{Foo stuff}
\end{document}
```

[image]